# PHP reading and moving a file at the same time

Tags: php

the situation is as follows, there's a `cronjob` that executes every second, it loops over a directory and grabs a file. To stop this file being processed twice I move it to another directory with `rename()` and get the content of the file( at the new directory ) with `file_get_contents()` and then use `json_decode()` on it. It seems that for bigger files it fails to move the whole file and uses the decode function so fails to decode it. What might be the best approach to ensure that the whole file is moved and only then try to grab the content of it?

Comment: Did you try with "try" and "catch"?

Comment: This would not solve the problem of processing a partly moved file.

Comment: just rename the file and your processing ignores the renamed files. for example cronjob gets file.txt and renames it to file.wip

Comment: Of course not, I was referring to know IF the file was moved and then try to grab the content of it. I think this could be the cause of some php.ini setting...

Comment: Would getting the content of the file before I move the file work? Or might it still get only part of the file and start moving it?

Comment: This way it should work, I think. Because the limit seems a memory-related limit. But if you need the document to remain the same even after renaming it (for future reference), we need to understand what is the problem. 
Getting the content before moving it is a workaround but not a complete solution...
Could you post the code (editing the question) the code that handles this actions?